# Normalized vector formed from correlated Gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation, gaussian

Take independent Gaussians $\mathbf{g_1}, \mathbf{g_2} \thicksim N(0,1)$ and define correlated Gaussians $z_1 = \mathbf{g_1} + \mu_1$ and $z_2 = \rho_1 \mathbf{g_1} + \rho_2 \mathbf{g_2} + \mu_2$. Since this is an affine linear transform of the form,
$$\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\rho_1 & \rho_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}g_1\\g_2\end{bmatrix}$$
we can equivalently consider,
$$\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix} \thicksim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\rho_1 & \rho_2\end{bmatrix} I \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\\rho_1 & \rho_2\end{bmatrix}^T\right) = N\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1\\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 & \rho_1\\\rho_1 & \rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2\end{bmatrix} \right)$$
Now consider the unit vector,
$$(v_1,v_2) = \mathcal{N}(z_1, z_2) := \frac{(z_1,z_2)}{\sqrt{z_1^2 + z_2^2}}$$
I would like to understand the expected value of this vector, as a function of the parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2, \rho_1, \rho_2$. Does this vector follow any well-understood distribution? I was able to compute the 2nd-order moments $\mathbb E[v_1^2]$ and $\mathbb E[v_1v_2]$ by observing that it's a ratio of quadratic forms (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394268/multivariate-gaussian-integral-of-ratio-of-quadratic-forms)), but I was unable to find / come up with a similar notion for the 1st-order moments.

Relatedly, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268661/what-is-the-law-of-the-ratio-of-two-independent-gaussian-randon-variables) asking about the ratio of independent Gaussian random variables, which led me to Student's t-distribution. However, this seems to be different in a few crucial ways, like $z_1$ and $z_2$ being correlated Gaussians, rather than independent draw from a normal distribution. Also, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ were just both drawn from $N(0,1)$, this would be equivalent to considering a uniformly random vector from $S^1$ (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864519/normalized-vector-of-gaussian-variables-is-uniformly-distributed-on-the-sphere)). Perhaps this could be viewed as a transformation of the such a vector $v \in S^1$? I'm thrown off by the normalization.